# Is device_data always provided in a call back?

Tags: paypal, braintree

When using the [PayPal JS v2 SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2), we *usually* a get `device_data` parameter in the call back.

I wasn't able to find any reference to this parameter, except in the `Braintree::Transaction.sale` [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#device_data).

---

In production we intermittently see that no `device_data` parameter comes with the call back.

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. What causes it, and are there any implications?
3. Should we simply omit passing `device_data` on to `Braintree::Transaction.sale`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`device_data` is a piece of parameter that contains various information about the customer device for fraud detection. Things like, `device_session_id`, `fraud_merchant_id`, `correlation_id` will be part of the device data. All these information are for fraud detection and risk information.

This is something which you should provide whenever you look for support in the future.

I am not sure if this is an issue/intended to have no `device_data` returned in the callback, perhaps you should give them a call at 877.434.2894 or [email their Support team](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/) to check if there is an issue on this.

However, if you are not passing the `device_data` parameter in `Braintree::Transaction.sale`, I suppose that is fine. But the best practice is to have that piece of information.